# R stackedBar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

If this is my dataset.

```
   Surgery   Surv_Prob            Group
   CV          0.5113        Diabetic
   Hip         0.6619        Diabetic
   Knee        0.6665        Diabetic
   QFox        0.7054        Diabetic

   CV          0.5113    Non-Diabetic
   Hip         0.6629    Non-Diabetic
   Knee        0.6744    Non-Diabetic
   QFox        0.7073    Non-Diabetic
```

How do i plot a stacked bar plot like this below.

[image]

Please note the values are already cumulative in nature, so the plot should show a very little increase from CV to Hip (delta = 0.6619- 0.5113)

And the order should be CV -> Hip -> Knee -> QFox

Answer (score 2):

There could be a way where you can plot the cumulative values directly, however one way is to get the actual value and plot the stacked bar plot by arranging the `Surgery` data in the order you want using `factor`. For `factor` levels I have used `rev(unique(Surgery))` for convenience as you want order in opposite order of how they appear in the dataset. For more complex types you might need to add `levels` manually.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Surv_Prob1 = c(Surv_Prob[1], diff(Surv_Prob)), 
         Surgery = factor(Surgery, levels = rev(unique(Surgery)))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Group, Surv_Prob1, fill = Surgery, label = Surv_Prob) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Surgery = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L), .Label = c("CV", "Hip", "Knee", "QFox"), class = "factor"), 
Surv_Prob = c(0.5113, 0.6619, 0.6665, 0.7054, 0.5113, 0.6629, 
0.6744, 0.7073), Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Diabetic", "Non-Diabetic"), class = 
"factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```